# .htaccess not working but is enabled

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file that isn't working.  I know it's not working because i wrote random things in it and i am not getting a 500 error.  Even when i write proper code it doesn't work. I have verified that is in my root directory and has the proper file name.  Here is the directory "tag" from http.conf:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I used `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and verified that mod_rewrite is enabled, but still no luck.

Comment: Anything useful in the Apache error log?

Comment: @ShaneMadden how do i do that.  im not getting any error when i run my htaccess in my directory.  the pages load like normal

Comment: Open the Apache error log and look for any errors that are relevant.  The log's location is variable based on how it was installed and what system you're on.

Comment: @ShaneMadden it seems that ive gotten about a hundred errors and all of them are the same thing.  "[Thu Jan 19 21:50:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico"

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if that `Deny from all` might be the problem.  If Apache knows it's going to send a 403 response, it might not even bother reading the .htaccess file.

Other potential problems could include a typo in the name of the `.htaccess` file (although you did say you'd checked this), a different `AccessFileName` value to normal and file/directory permissions on any of the directories leading up to your DocumentRoot.

It might be worth using strace to verify that Apache is actually reading your `.htaccess` file.  Make sure Apache is stopped then start it this way:

```
sudo strace -f -e open apache2 -X
```

Then make your request again.

Comment: "If Apache knows it's going to send a 403 response, it might not even bother reading the .htaccess file." - That doesn't happen. The `.htaccess` file could potentially override the `Deny from all` (defined in a parent _directory_ context).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <Directory />
> Options FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All
> ```

You should never set `AllowOverride All` for the entire filesystem (ie. inside the `<Directory />` container). This should be (and defaults to) `AllowOverride None` for a reason. And Apache explicitly warns against doing this.

Setting `AllowOverride All` here will cause Apache to scan for `.htaccess` files all the way up the directory tree to the root.

The most likely reason why your `.htaccess` file is not being processed is that you have a more *specific* `<Directory>` container (possibly in a `<VirtualHost>`) elsewhere in your config that has set `AllowOverride None`, overriding the setting in `<Directory />` for that directory tree.

However, by setting `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory />` then Apache is quite likely scanning for `.htaccess` files in all *parent* directories which could result in performance and security issues.

> ```
> <Directory />
> :
> Deny from all
> ```

You must have a more specific `<Directory>` container somewhere since your site is presumably accessible? (I assume you are not getting a "403 Forbidden" response?)